# Ghost mathjax inlining not working

Tags: mathjax, ghost-blog, ghost

I've read this post on how to add inline math mode to ghost :

http://ghost-rkingsbury.rhcloud.com/how-to-add-mathjax-to-a-ghost-blog/

I've added to Settings -> Code Injection :

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">  
   MathJax.Hub.Config({
     tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']],
     processEscapes: true}          
   });
</script>  
<script type="text/javascript" async  
src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">  
</script>
```

but receive error :

```
jquery.fitvids.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at jquery.fitvids.js:16
    at jquery.fitvids.js:67
index.js:56 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at index.js:56
localhost/:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at EVAL (MathJax.js:19)
    at Function.execute (MathJax.js:19)
    at cb (MathJax.js:19)
    at Object.Process (MathJax.js:19)
    at Object.Push (MathJax.js:19)
    at Object.ConfigBlocks (MathJax.js:19)
    at Function.execute (MathJax.js:19)
    at cb (MathJax.js:19)
    at Object.Process (MathJax.js:19)
```

Removing :

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">  
   MathJax.Hub.Config({
     tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']],
     processEscapes: true}          
   });
</script>
```

allows MathJax to be rendered but $...$ is not recognized as an inline math statement

Adding jQuery library to Code Injection :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">  
   MathJax.Hub.Config({
     tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']],
     processEscapes: true}          
   });
</script>  
<script type="text/javascript" async  
src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">  
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

results in error :

```
VM411:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at EVAL (MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML:19)
    at Function.execute (MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML:19)
    at cb (MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML:19)
    at Object.Process (MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML:19)
    at Object.Push (MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML:19)
    at Object.ConfigBlocks (MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML:19)
    at Function.execute (MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML:19)
    at cb (MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML:19)
    at Object.Process (MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML:19)
EVAL @ MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML:19
execute @ MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML:19
cb @ MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML:19
Process @ MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML:19
Push @ MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML:19
ConfigBlocks @ MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML:19
execute @ MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML:19
cb @ MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML:19
Process @ MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML:19
call @ MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML:19
WAITEXECUTE @ MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML:19
cb @ MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML:19
Execute @ MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML:19
loadComplete @ MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML:19
(anonymous) @ TeX-MML-AM_CHTML.js?V=2.7.0:68
```

Am I missing a step trying to embed inline functionality in Ghost ?

Comment: Do you have a link to a live sample exhibits the problem?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger I don't have live example as I'm just running Ghost locally.

Comment: It's hard to say much without being able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Does my answer help?

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, cf. https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/.

Comment: Thank you for asking, I faced the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

I am using Ghost for my [blog](//johnsiu.com).

1. `MathJax.Hub.Config` and script source need to be in one script block for async to work correctly, else `MathJax.Hub.Config` will be defined before `MathJax.js` is available and generate an error.
2. Use double quote(") in code injection. This may due to Ghost template parsing. If single quote (') is used, the line is chopped off right after the first quote.

Ghost demo page: https://johnsiu.com/mathjax-test/

Demo page raw data:

```
Inline : $ y = \int_0^1 {1\over x} dx $
Standalone: $$ y = \int_0^1 {1\over x} dx $$

<script type="text/javascript" async src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    tex2jax: {
        inlineMath: [["$", "$"], ["\\(", "\\)"]],
        processEscapes: true
    }
});
</script>
```

If you use `mathjax` extensively in your side, move the script block into Ghost `Setting->Code Injection` header or footer.

Tested with FF and Chrome browser.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, cf. https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Thanks for the info! I updated the answer to use cdnjs opensource cdn.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helped me in using inline MathJax on my blog - blog.vcillusion.co.in